# Decorator Pattern, Subclasses running through other subclasses to get behavior?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, decorator, aggregation

I've been going through the Decorator Pattern and I understand the theory pretty well, however theres just a slight technical part that I can't get my head around.

I understand that you can add decorators so that when you call an object, it calls all of the decorator functions as well so that they can change the behaviour (Such as adding ingredients to a Coffee). What I don't understand is how its possible.

```
Coffee c = new SimpleCoffee();

c = new Whip(new Sprinkles(new Milk(c)));
System.out.println("Cost: " + c.getCost() + "; Ingredients: " + c.getIngredients());
```

This adds the extra cost and ingredients to the functions by using the decorator classes: Milk, Whip and Sprinkles. However, this individual implementation is like:

```
class Milk extends CoffeeDecorator {
    public Milk (Coffee decoratedCoffee) {
        super(decoratedCoffee);
    }

    public double getCost() { 
        return super.getCost() + 0.5;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return super.getIngredients() + ingredientSeparator + "Milk";
    }
}
```

I don't see anywhere where they reference each other, they only reference the super class which regardless of the subclass would be the coffee decorator, so in the above example where c = new Whip(new Sprinkles(new Milk(c))), how does it receive all the extra functionality?

Its hard to explain, but how exactly does:

```
c = new Whip(new Sprinkles(new Milk(c)))
```

Work in terms of inheritance/aggregation? Do they run through each other?

The full program is at Wikipedia, I didn't write any of the examples used, they can all be found at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That's right they are extending each other from the abstract Coffee class.  They are not adding new methods but change the way that existing ones return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Milk, Whip etc. classes extend the CoffeeDecorator. That class takes the Coffee object in it's constructor.
Look at the implementation of the getCost in the ConcreteDecorator class. It only calls the getCost operation in the decorated class.

So when you have a hierarchy like:

```
c = new Whip(new Sprinkles(new Milk(c)))
```

And run:

```
c.getCost();
```

The order of operation is something like this:

```
The Whip instance runs the super.getCost() - in fact calling sprinkles.getCost()
The sprinkles.getCost() runs **its** super.getCost() - in fact calling Milk.getCost()
...
The coffee object returns 1
...
The sprinkles object adds its cost to that
The whip object adds its cost to the result.
```